# Dynamic Tag Context Compliment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

This is some of the information provided by the docs for dynamic tag contexts in acts_as_taggable_on...

```
@user = User.new(:name => "Bobby")
@user.set_tag_list_on(:customs, "same, as, tag, list")
@user.tag_list_on(:customs) # => ["same","as","tag","list"]
@user.save
@user.tags_on(:customs) # => [<Tag name='same'>,...]
@user.tag_counts_on(:customs)
User.tagged_with("same", :on => :customs) # => [@user]
```

My question is how do I get a compliment of the custom tag list that I create. I want :tags - :customs, that is the set of all tags minus the specified tags of customs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their Github page:

```
# Find a user that's not tagged with awesome or cool:
User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :exclude => true)
```

---

### Update

---

You could try:

```
customs_tags = @user.tag_list_on(:customs)
user_tags = @user.tag_list
new_tags = user_tags - customs_tags

@user.set_tag_list_on(:customs, new_tags)
```

Comment: Cool, but how do I go about setting the tag list to be a compliment?

@user.set_tag_list_on(:customs, "same, as, tag, list", :exclude => true) for example...

Comment: So you want to set the `tag_list` on `:customs` to all `tags`, excluding the `tags` that are already in `customs_list`?  That's what it looks like you're trying to do above.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for ;)